# Customizing email headers in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-headers, email-notifications

I am trying to write a filter that changes the reply-to address for WooCommerce email, dependent on the 'billing city' the order is made for.

This works for WooCommerce emails, but doesn't seem to work for WooCommerce Advanced notifications - it doesn't seem to pass the '$order' into the header information to do the IF statement.

It is a long shot but any thoughts much appreciated. This is my code.

```
function change_headers($order, $object, $headers);

// Get the city 
$city = $order->get_billing_city();

// Change Headers

if ($city == 'Manchester') {
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Reply-to: Manchester <manchester@city.org>';
return $headers;
} else {
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Reply-to: London <london@city.org>';
return $headers;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'change_headers', 10, 3);
```

This is the code in WooCommerce Advanced Notifications plugin.

```
/**
 * sends an email through WooCommerce with the correct headers
 */
public function send( $id, $object, $is_plain_text, $to, $subject, $message, $notification ) {
    $email = new WC_Email();

    if ( $is_plain_text ) {
        $message = wordwrap( strip_tags( $message ), 60 );
        $email->email_type = 'plain';
    } else {
        $email->email_type = 'html';
    }

    $email->id = "advanced_notification_{$notification->notification_id}";

    $email->send( $to, $subject, $message, $email->get_headers(), $email->get_attachments() );
}
```

**PROGRESS EDIT**

So now based on Loic's kind advice I've applied his code (below) but it throws this Fatal error with WooCommerce Advanced Notifications enabled. This is because for some reason the '$order' argument is not correctly passed through to the filter on WooCommerce Advanced Notifications emails so $city = $order->get_billing_city(); is empty.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_billing_city() on null in /home/benefacto/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/bnfo-custom-emails/bnfo-custom-emails.php:130 Stack trace: #0 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): custom_email_notification_headers('Content-Type: t...', 'advanced_notifi...', NULL) #1 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev/wp-includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters('Content-Type: t...', Array) #2 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php(287): apply_filters('woocommerce_ema...', 'Content-Type: t...', 'advanced_notifi...', NULL) #3 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-advanced-notifications/includes/class-wc-advanced-notifications.php(257): WC_Email->get_headers(NULL) #4 /home/benefacto/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-advanced-notifications/includes/class-wc-advanced-notifications.php(319): WC_Advanced_Notifications->send('new_order', Object(WC_Order), '0', 'l in /home/benefacto/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/bnfo-custom-emails/bnfo-custom-emails.php on line 130
```

Answer (score 2):

You have inverted the arguments in your function regarding **`woocommerce_email_headers`** filter hook *(Note: I don't use WooCommerce Advanced Notifications plugin)*.

Instead try this (I have make some little changes):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_email_notification_headers', 10, 3 );
function custom_email_notification_headers( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {

    // Get the city
    $city = $order->get_billing_city();

    $headers = array( $headers );

    if ($city == 'Manchester')
    {
        $headers[] = 'Reply-to: Manchester <manchester@city.org>';
    }
    else
    {
        $headers[] = 'Reply-to: London <london@city.org>';
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce versions 3+ and works.

Comment: I've tested and unfortunately it doesn't work with WooCommerce Advanced Notifications - I've explained why in my edit above. Any further thoughts?! Thanks Loic.

Comment: @LinzDarlington So sorry for you … You should need to find a filter hook in this plugin source code as it's dont seem to use classic woocommerce core functions or methods…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/51558359/8913606

Comment: @melvin You asked me to help on your code… I have answer as I can, because your code is not testable.

Comment: @it's just a sample. i cannot provide the exact code to test due to confidentiality

Comment: @melvin Then I can't provide a correct answer due to this confidentiality *(then, next time if is not clear and testable, is better to don't ask me)*. **Remember that:** "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**."*.